# How Do I make the button load a diffrent video when click

Tags: javascript, html

So I made a "Streaming website" and I struggle with the episode buttons to change the video, each episode btn has an Id

Here is my html code:

```
 <div class="episode">
          <div class="play-btn">
            <a href="#">
              <button id="mybtn1" onclick="playEpisode(1)" type="button" name="button">
                <div class="play">
                  <svg viewBox="0 0 26 26">
                    <polygon class="play-btn-svg" points="9.33 6.69 9.33 19.39 19.3 13.04 9.33 6.69" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <span>1</span> Underworld
              </button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

  <div class="Videocontainer">
      <div class="Videowindow">
        <video  class="myvideo" autoplay poster="Sword art Online\SAO S1\play.jpg" controls >
          <source src="Sword art Online\SAO S1\[HorribleSubs] Sword Art Online - Alicization - 01 [1080p].mkv" class="videoSource">
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I tried this code but it does not work

js Code:

```
var myVideo = document.querySelectorAll("Videowindow");
var btnVideo1 = document.getElementById("mybtn1");
var btnVideo2 = document.getElementById("mybtn2");
var btnVideo3 = document.getElementById("mybtn3");

// Add event listeners for the "click" event on the buttons
btnVideo1.addEventListener("click", function() {
// Update the video source with video 1
myVideo.src = "Sword art Online\\SAO S1\[HorribleSubs\] Sword Art Online - Alicization - 01 \[1080p\].mkv";
myVideo.load(); // Load the new video source
});

btnVideo2.addEventListener("click", function() {
// Update the video source with video 2
myVideo.src = "Sword art Online\\SAO S1\[HorribleSubs\] Sword Art Online - Alicization - 02 \[1080p\].mkv";
myVideo.load(); // Load the new video source
});

btnVideo3.addEventListener("click", function() {
// Update the video source with video 3
myVideo.src = "Sword art Online\\SAO S1\[HorribleSubs\] Sword Art Online - Alicization - 03 \[1080p\].mkv";
myVideo.load(); // Load the new video source
});
```

Comment: Your `myVideo` variable contains a list of `<div class="Videowindow">` elements, not video elements. Change the first line to `var myVideo = document.querySelector(".myvideo");` to select the first `<video>` element with the class `.myvideo`.

Comment: For future reference, please check your browser console to see any errors. You definitely should see some regarding the `load()` function not existing on the div element.

Comment: `.mkv` files won't work though. You can use `mp4`, `webm`, `ogg`

Comment: The .mkv does work and it does also plays